# Why is my TabBar not rendering correctly in top position in react native router flux?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

My tab bar will render fine when tabBarPosition is set to bottom but does not display correctly when I set the tabBarPosition to top.

Here is my code for the bottom position (this is for the dashboard scene).

```
   <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
        <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true} tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#eee' }} showLabel={false}>
          <Scene key="search" title="Search" icon={TabIcon} initial={true}>
            <Scene key="searchHome" component={HomeScene} title="Search" initial={true}/>
            <Scene key="searchResults" component={SearchResultsScene} title="Search Results" />
          </Scene>
          <Scene key="dash" icon={TabIcon} title="Dashboad">
              <Scene key="dashTabs" tabs={true} tabBarPosition="bottom" tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#eee' }} showLabel={false} >
                <Scene key="profile" component={ProfileScene} title="Profile" icon={TabIcon} initial={true}/>
                <Scene key="messaging" component={MessagingScene} title="Messaging" icon={TabIcon}/>
                <Scene key="settings" component={SettingsScene} title="Settings" icon={TabIcon}/>
              </Scene>
          </Scene>
          <Scene key="auth" title="Login" icon={TabIcon}>
            <Scene key="login" component={LoginScene} title="Login" />
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

This is how it looks and how I would like it to behave but obviously with the top tab bar right below the navbar.

[image: tabBarPosition="bottom"]

Tab bar position top

```
 <Scene key="dashTabs" tabs={true} tabBarPosition="top" tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#eee', top: 100 }} showLabel={false} >
```

[image]

I set the top value to 100 just for demonstration purposes. I would use a dynamic value based on the height of the navbar.

You can see that the labels don't show up, there is a margin between the top of the screen and the navbar, there is a yellow bottom border on the active tab and the TabIcon component is not rendered.

Is this because top tab bar is the default for Android and the styling is different than the bottom bar (default for Ios)?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.51.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.24",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"redux": "^3.7.2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the following way

```
<Scene key="dash" icon={TabIcon} title="Dashboad">
              <Scene key="dashTabs" tabs={true} tabBarPosition="bottom" tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#eee' }} showLabel={false} showIcon activeTintColor="purple"
              inactiveTintColor="black"
              labelStyle={{ flexWrap: 'nowrap' }}
              indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} >
                <Scene key="profile" component={ProfileScene} title="Profile" icon={TabIcon} initial={true}/>
                <Scene key="messaging" component={MessagingScene} title="Messaging" icon={TabIcon}/>
                <Scene key="settings" component={SettingsScene} title="Settings" icon={TabIcon}/>
              </Scene>
          </Scene>
```

Use showIcon to show your icons and background colours will be applied through styles. Refer to this link for `tabBarPosition='Top'` props that can be used in case of tab bar position set to top
[TabBar position=top props that can be used.](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/docs/api/navigators/TabNavigator.md#tabbaroptions-for-tabbartop-default-tab-bar-on-android)

Comment: I was able to get my tab styling back when I included the showIcon prop and indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} got rid of the yellow bottom border. The tabBar is still above the navBar though. When I set the top value to the height of the navbar, the tab bar goes below the nav bar but there is padding above the nav bar equal to the height of the tab bar. Like in the second image of the OP. Thanks for the help!